# RestAPI C# .net core pass a single string to post request. not reaching endpoint

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core, http-post

I have a very simple need.
1, Send single string to calling endpoint using POST method.
2, Don't want Get request at all. Don't want to create model for incoming/outgoing params .

I have tried almost everything I can find online. most of the example is creating DTO object which seems overkill just to send simple string. Due to size of string, HTTPGet is not recommended. I am getting endpoint NOT FOUND ERROR

```
[Route("GetVar")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GetVar([FromBody] string incomingvar)
{                     
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"10pk" );            
} 

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetVar(string incomingvar)
    {       
        var content = "{\"incomingvar\" : incomingvar}";
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content, Formatting.Indented);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(json);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
          return await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
    }
```

Comment: What does the top of your controller for your api look like? For example
`[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class V1Controller : ControllerBase` Does it have any of these?

Comment: This controller works fine. There is other http get methods works fine. Even some of the post method works fine but in those methods object model is being passed.                                                                                                                                 [System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/controller)                                         
 public class V1Controller : ApiController

Comment: Check  my answer below. Tested a post method in dotnet api and the convention below worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
[HttpPost("GetVar")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetVar([FromBody] object incomingvar)
{
   //Do work here
}
```

Then call your method like so: https://localhost:7292/api/controllername/GetVar

Obviously your localhost part and port will be different, but idea is same.

Comment: Thanks! so it seems like even for simple string I have to send it as an object. I just wanted it to be very simple. sending and receiving both ends accepting string datatype and doesn't need jsonobject and conversion etc. but it seems like impossible

Comment: Great if this works, mind marking as correct so if others run into problem they can resolve easily.